# Stop SMS from moving to Inbox

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-4.4-kitkat

Before Android 4.4 I was able to stop messages from moving to inbox by setting the priority like this

```
    <receiver android:name="com.serviceschedular.helperClasses.SmsReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />          
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and then abortBroadcast() in onRecieve() messages.  However in Android 4.4 we need to define SMS_DELIVER_ACTION in order to make our messaging app as default :

[Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

By doing this I can receive messages first and they don't move to any other messaging app but I also need to send them to messaging app if it doesn't fill my criteria. So is there any way around to achieve this functionality?