# Stop messages to go in Inbox

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, telephony

I have listed all the incoming msgs in a LIstView and then showing user details of msgs on tap of particular msg. Now I want one more addon feature that the messages should be stopped from going into inbox.

I have used `abortBroadcast()`,but still it is not working.

Please help me out as I am new to android programming.

Answer (score 0):

Android had changed their policy terms(kitkat or above), only the default app can have write permission.

If you want to filter the SMS getting into inbox, you must need specify app as default app.

For More detail -->
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Comment: I have gone through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21823445/stop-sms-from-moving-to-inbox?rq=1] and had came to a solution that stopping sms to go into inbox is not possible in Android 4 (KitKat)and above